# ASP.NET Blazor web app in Linux Docker container does not load styles.css at all

Tags: css, linux, docker, asp.net-core, blazor

[image]
It does not load because it is looking at the wwwroot folder but it is not there. Building Blazor Web App Linux Docker containers.When I click Web Docker Launch button on that image, it generates the css file in the  ‘obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle’ folder in my host machine's project folder. But in the container, when it loads the page, it is looking for the CSS in the wwwroot folder which is missing. So I manually copy it to the wwwroot folder in the container. But when that happens, it is also automatically being copied to the wwwroot project folder in my host machine. I did not bind the folders and I did not manually mount them as volumes folders. It automatically binds the wwwroot folders. so How can I prevent the wwwroot folder of my host machine from binding with the wwwroot folder of the container?

If I do not manually copy the AccSol.styles.css to the wwwroot folder in the docker container, it will not load the styles but if I manually copy it there, it will load but the next time I launch my docker compose file it will produce this error (see image below) maybe because of what the visual studio build process is doing which is trying to copy the CSS file to the wwwroot but when I look in File Explorer it is not there:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       Conflicting assets with the same target path 'AccSol.styles.css'. 
For 'All' assets 'Identity: C:\repo\AccSol\AccSol\obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle\AccSol.styles.css, 
SourceType: Computed, SourceId: AccSol, ContentRoot: C:\repo\AccSol\AccSol\obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle\, BasePath: _content/AccSol, 
RelativePath: AccSol.styles.css, AssetKind: All, AssetMode: CurrentProject, AssetRole: 
Primary, AssetRole: , AssetRole: , RelatedAsset: , AssetTraitName: ScopedCss, 
AssetTraitValue: ApplicationBundle, CopyToOutputDirectory: Never, CopyToPublishDirectory: 
PreserveNewest, OriginalItemSpec: 
C:\repo\AccSol\AccSol\obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle\AccSol.styles.css' and 'Identity: 
C:\repo\AccSol\AccSol\wwwroot\AccSol.styles.css, SourceType: Discovered, SourceId: AccSol, 
ContentRoot: C:\repo\AccSol\AccSol\wwwroot\, BasePath: _content/AccSol, RelativePath: 
AccSol.styles.css, AssetKind: All, AssetMode: All, AssetRole: Primary, AssetRole: , 
AssetRole: PreferTarget, RelatedAsset: , AssetTraitName: , AssetTraitValue: , 
CopyToOutputDirectory: Never, CopyToPublishDirectory: PreserveNewest, OriginalItemSpec: 
wwwroot\AccSol.styles.css'. AccSol  C:\Program
```

Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.StaticWebAssets\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.St
aticWebAssets.targets   475

[image]

Can I create a script that would check if they are bound together and prevent them from binding?